# linear regression with more than one weighted variable

Tags: regression, python, weighted-regression

I have a data set with the variables: y,n,date,x1,x2,x3.
I'm trying to predict y through x1,x2,x3 - categorical variables.
I'm building a linear regression model in python.
I'm interested in using weights:

- n - number of observation per row
- date - give more weight to more recent data (will use some power function here)

I know how to use regression with one variable that represent weight:

```
regr = linear_model.LinearRegression()
model1=regr.fit(X, y,sample_weight=n)
```

My question is- does it make sense to use two weighting variables (n,date) ? and how can I do it in python ?

Thanks

Comment: I think you mean "does it make sense ..." rather than does it make since...".

Comment: The conceptual part of your question may well be answered on this site.  The python part would need to be asked elsewhere.

Comment: To my understanding, weight should be the inverse of variance.

Comment: You cannot use different weights for different variables in `sklearn`.